# NullPointerExeception on a Geopoint

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

I have the following set-up

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {    

GeoPoint pointTarget;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pointTarget.setLatitude(51.4245);
    pointTarget.setLongitude(3.1455);

    }
}
```

This throws `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference` at `pointTarget.setLatitude(51.4245);`

The two arguments are doubles, so that can't be the problem. `pointTarget` has also been instantiated. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for referring to "*What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?*". I have now instantiated as `private GeoPoint pointTarget = new GeoPoint(0.0,0.0);`, which solved the problem. Perhaps I should switch to Kotlin, which apparently has no NullPointerExceptions.